# how to put large records in csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am creating a csv file but there are 9700 records in database but around 6800 rows are inserting in csv file, please advise how can I do it, i have heard about saving data in temp file and then putting it in csv , i am not sure how to do that

```
$valArr = $fieldArr['field_value'];
if(!empty($arrvalH_VH))
    $valArr = array_merge($fieldArr['field_value'],$arrvalH_VH);
if(!empty($field_value_arr))
    $valArr = array_merge($valArr,$field_value_arr);
fputcsv($file, $valArr);
```

Thanks

Comment: How script is being used. Is it being called via CLI or via a Webserver?

Comment: @KamranSyed its using webserver

Comment: Can you include more of the script - how do you retrieve the data from the database for example.

Comment: @NigelRen I found out it was max_input_vars issue, it were storing 7498 form_id only in array

Answer (score 0):

With the long processes like data import/export, there is a good probability that PHP maximum execution timeout is terminating the script before completion. Execution timeout can be increased by following setting in php.ini.

```
    max_execution_time = 360 // Timeout value is in seconds
```

As an alternate the same setting can be changed from PHP code as below:

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '360');
```

NOTE: If restricted by server admin, you will not be able to set max_execution_time. This is the case with most shared hosting providers.